# Subscript out of Range/ Next Row

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

So I'm trying to write a code where I can log info on another sheet on SharePoint through a macro, and I keep getting a subscript out of range error starting with `masterNextRow`. What's going wrong?

```vb
Sub Scan()
    Dim wbLocal As Workbook
    Dim wbMaster As Workbook
    Dim masterNextRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer
        
    Set wbLocal = ThisWorkbook
    Set wbMaster = Workbooks.Open("https://.....my.sharepoint.co....")
                   
    masterNextRow = wbMaster.Worksheets("Daily Log").Range("A" & wbMaster.Worksheets("Daily Log").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

    wbMaster.Worksheets("Daily Log").Cells(masterNextRow, 1).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Input").Range("H7").Value
    wbMaster.Worksheets("Daily Log").Cells(masterNextRow, 2).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Input").Range("B4").Value
    wbMaster.Worksheets("Daily Log").Cells(masterNextRow, 3).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Input").Range("B5").Value
    wbMaster.Worksheets("Daily Log").Cells(masterNextRow, 4).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Input").Range("B6").Value
    wbMaster.Worksheets("Daily Log").Cells(masterNextRow, 5).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Input").Range("B7").Value
    
    wbMaster.Close True
End Sub
```

Comment: Because you don't have a worksheet called Daily Log?

Comment: No I do acctually. That's what I don't understand!

Comment: Are you sure it's `"Daily Log"`? Not `"Daily  Log"`, `" Daily Log"` or `"Daily log "`?

Comment: yes I've checked all the spaces and even copy/pasted it the same! Could there be any other explanation?

Comment: Remove the space in the sheet name maybe it is 0160 instead of 0032